# Is there an R function for adding more years to the x axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want all the years of my database to be shown on the x-axis. I do not want to be separated for five years. What do I need to use to solve this problem?

This is my database-Peru (Base_PER_98) [Data of Peru since 1998](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u98jK.png)

```
structure(list(year = c(1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 
2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 
2016, 2017), recaudacion = c(14.2348049647571, 12.9941892981826, 
12.6086474992247, 12.8971056336871, 12.4871426273152, 13.411521163568, 
13.6633689429004, 14.1047421923916, 15.6699876015142, 16.4074683503203, 
16.5121709202423, 14.4565268083919, 15.4665717570431, 15.9688951452089, 
16.5466871027669, 16.4295609212116, 16.6957115868799, 14.9101529795257, 
13.8170890083791, 13.1605934905758)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Database- LA and the Caribbean(Base_ALC_1998)
[Data of LA and the Caribbean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnvLm.png)

```
structure(list(year = c(1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 
2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 
2016, 2017), recaudacion = c(17.554, 17.752, 18.307, 18.511, 
18.486, 18.876, 19.35, 20.117, 21.133, 21.267, 21.547, 20.873, 
21.142, 21.518, 21.939, 21.921, 22.138, 22.702, 22.639, 22.823
)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

This is my code to graph both series in one plot:

```
ggplot(base_PER_98,aes(x=year,y=recaudacion)) +
      geom_line(aes(color="Peru 1998-2017")) +
      geom_line(data=base_ALC_1998,aes(color="ALC 1998-2017")) +
      labs(color="Legent text") +
      theme_minimal()+labs(title="ALC-Peru" , x="",y="PS(PBI%)")
```

I don't know what code I have to use if I  want all the years of my database to be shown on the x-axis. I do not want to be separated for 5 years.

I want this output:

[image: correct output]

But I have this:

[image: actual output]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with scale_x_continuous - something like this should work:

```
ggplot(base_PER_98,aes(x=year,y=recaudacion))+
    geom_line(aes(color="Peru 1998-2017")) +
    geom_line(data=base_ALC_1998,aes(color="ALC 1998-2017"))+
    labs(color="Legent text")+
    theme_minimal()+
    labs(title="ALC-Peru" , x="",y="PS(PBI%)")+
    scale_x_continuous(name="Year", labels=as.character(base_PER_98$year), breaks = base_PER_98$year)
```

Comment: Hi, I have this error:Error in check_breaks_labels(breaks, labels) : object 'year' not found

Comment: can you do `dput(base_PER_98)` and then paste the results in your original question so that your data can be reproducible?

Comment: Sure, I just did it

Comment: ok thanks! just made a small edit, this should give you what you want